# PHP date format formatting a year as future date (like 2050) instead of 1950 when date is less than 1970

Tags: php, date

I am formatting a date like '121654' as below;

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy','121654');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Now the output is;

**2054-12-16**

But I want it to be like 1954-12-16.

Up to 1970 it is giving correct result. But if year is less than 1970 it becomes a future date.

Is there any way to make things as I wanted.

Comment: Do you have any control over that input date? If yes, why are you replicating the Y2K problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Y as year to set 1954.

https://3v4l.org/4K7Ti

```
$in = "121654";
$in19 = Substr($in, 0,4) . "19". Substr($in, 4);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY',$in19);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: No my format has to be like 54, keeping this thing same, is it possible to do what I wanted keeping the thing same as it is.

Comment: How are you supposed to know if it's 1954 or 2054 or even 2154 then?

Comment: You could do some pre-processing, changing `'121654'` to `'12161954'`, and `'121618'` to `'12162018'`. You can choose where you put the switch from '19' to '20' but you can never cover more than one century.

Comment: Yes, I understand the fact. :(

Comment: Added 19 to string. But you should specify when you want 19 and when you want 20. Or it will be a poor generic answer.

Comment: I would check the `Substr($in, 4)` value, for instance, if it is bigger than `40` you can insert `19` otherwise you insert `20`. You have to account for dates like 2016. It is your answer Andreas. :-)

Comment: @KIKO that is what I'm saying OP needs to specify. You see 16 as 2016. But it could be 1916 or 2116 too. There has to be some limits that OP has not shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Y` instead of `y` and specify 1954 here.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY','12161954');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: No my format has to be like 54, keeping this thing same, is it possible to do what I wanted keeping the thing same as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check if the date generated is less than 1970 then you can use functions to add **X** year to it, so it will be in the future :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY','12161960');
$date1970 = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY','01011970');
if ($date < $date1970) {
    $newDate = $date->modify('+500 years');
}
echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is guaranteed to be `MMDDYY`, I'd approach it by fixing the data itself:

```
list($m, $d, $y) = str_split('121654', 2);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY', "$m{$d}19$y");
```

You can even add a step there in-between to test some custom cutoff year, e.g.:

```
if ($y > 20) {  // or whatever your logic is
    $y = "19$y";
}
```